# Pygraphviz- Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored warnings.warn(b"".join(errors).decode(self.encoding), RuntimeWarning)

Tags: python, graphviz, large-data, graph-visualization, pygraphviz

I am new to Graphviz, and I am trying a large graph with 7315 edges using the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import pygraphviz as pgv
g = pgv.AGraph()

ds = pd.read_csv("G:\cit-Patents_7315_1037462.txt",header=None)

ds.rename(columns={0:'col1'},inplace = True)
ds.rename(columns={1:'col2'},inplace = True)

for index, row in ds.iterrows():
    g.add_edge(str(row["col1"]), str(row["col2"]))
g.layout(prog='fdp')

g.draw('7315.svg')
```

When g.layout() is called, the following warnings show up.

```
c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py:1390: RuntimeWarning: Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored
Warning: Overlap value "prism" unsupported - ignored

  warnings.warn(b"".join(errors).decode(self.encoding), RuntimeWarning)
```

I am stuck here and could not understand how to resolve the problem.
I appreciate any help provided.. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that your graphviz installation lacks the GTS library (see the dependencies at https://graphviz.org/download/source/). How to install this library depends on your operating system and can be looked up at http://gts.sourceforge.net/install.html.